# Rails 3 create and average multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, average

I have two models Clients and Reports. A Client has_many Reports and a Report belongs_to a Client. A Client has a :specialty attribute (doctor, dentist, lawyer) and a Report has an :amount attribute. There are 4 Reports generated per year on calendar quarters for each Client.

What I want to do is to be able to average the :amounts over the entries for a given :specialty, say lawyers. I can get one big array with these values from this particular :specialty like this:

```
Quarter.includes(:client).where('clients.specialty=?','Lawyer').map(&:amounts)%>
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to print an array for each Client with that :specialty, and then average them in another array. Do I use a loop here like this:

```
<% Quarter.includes(:client).where('clients.specialty=?', 'Lawyer').each do |c| %>
<%= c.amount  %>
<% end %>
```

If so, how do I separate it out so that instead of just one huge array, they are separate based on the client that it belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `group` method.

For each specialty:

```
Quarter.includes(:client).group('clients.specialty').average('quarters.amounts')
```

This will return an `OrderedHash` which key is the `specialty` column specified in `group` and value is the corresponding average amounts

For each client:

```
Quarter.includes(:client).group('clients.id').average('quarters.amounts')
```

Comment: That's close. That gives me an average over the whole cumulative data set. I'm looking for an average for each time period that the data has been entered. Example, each calendar quarter of the year has one :amount entry per client (4 per year per client). Let's say there are two clients of the same :specialty, I want the average :amount for a given :quarter and :year. The only way I can think to make it work is to assign a variable to each period of time and query it that way instead of retrieving all records. Thoughts?

Comment: @FattRyan is there a `year` column in `Quarter`? If so, I think you can specify multiple column in `.group()` like `.group('clients.specialty', 'quarters.year')`.

Comment: @FattRyan But if you want to have both year average and quarter average within a single row, you must write a complex sql statement to retrieve it, or query twice and combine the results.

Comment: ShiningRay, adding more to the ".group()" function works just exactly as I wanted. Now I just have to figure out how to only display the number in an array, because here is what the output looks like:                        {"[\"Orthodontist\", 2010, 1]":"475000.0","[\"Orthodontist\", 2010, 2]":"484500.0","[\"Orthodontist\", 2010, 3]":"494190.0","]}.             Any Thoughts?